# Packaging css with a widget

Tags: css, gwt, cssresource

I want to package up a widget to be easily included in an arbitrary project.  I don't want to require that the user link to my personally-created style sheet in their host page - I just want the css to be magically injected when they use my code.

I understand that CssResource can go some ways towards this dream, but after scouring documentation I haven't found any reference to natural type selectors.  For instance, I want to style the `<tr>`s in my widget without having to add a class name to each one.

Is this achievable with GWT?  GWT's own widgets all come pretty thoroughly styled, but it seems they've added a style class to every single element in the DOM!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track - a `CssResource` or UiBinder's inline [`<ui:style>`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World) will achieve what you're looking for. With regards to styling elements by type instead of class it certainly can be done:

```
<ui:UiBinder>
  <ui:style>
    .myTable tr {
      color: red;
    }
  </ui:style>

  <table class="{style.myTable}">
    <tr><td>A row!</td></tr>
  </table>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

GWT, however, has a reason for preferring explicit class names over descendent selectors: if you have the above style, for example, every time the browser renders a `<tr>` element it has to walk up the DOM and visit all of the ancestors of that element to see if any of them have the `.myTable` class. If your application uses a lot of `<tr>` elements (`<div>` would be a better example here), most of which don't have a `.myTable` ancestor, it can cause a noticeable decrease in rendering performance.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize it was smart enough to pick up those descendant selectors.  That's awesome!  I'll test them out myself, but I have two quick follow-ups: 1: can I specify multiple definitions, e.g. `.myTable tr {}` AND `.myTable div {}`? 2: can I specify multiple selectors-to-be-obfuscated in the same definition, e.g. `.myTable .myRow {}` to be applied to `<table class="{style.myTable}><tr class={style.myRow}>`?

Comment: Yes, both of those will work. Note that if you define `.myRow` the descendent selector (most likely) won't be necessary any more because nothing else in the application will have the same class name.

Comment: It would have helped me a lot to just think of GWT.create() going through and replacing every .myCustomName with some unique .SDFJSDFH .  I guess that's obvious now, but I was just thinking about this all wrong.  Thanks for the help!  Aside: I'd still need the selector if I'm going to have, like, .tableOfStyle1 .row {} and .tableOfStyle2 .row {}, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think, I would use UiBinder, and only give the outermost element a class name, like this:

```
<ui:style>
    .outer tr {
        ...
    }
</ui:style>
<div class="{style.outer}">
    ...
      <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</div>
```

Now you don't have to assign a class to each tr - you just use the selector "`.outer tr`", which only applies to `<tr>`s within some element marked with the class attribute `{style.outer}` (doesn't have to be a `<div>` by the way). The same principle would work without UiBinder, too, of course.

Comment: Thanks! This makes total sense, I just somehow didn't realize that GWT would be smart enough to just obfuscate the `.outer` and leave the rest in place.  Clever stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didn't really understand the whole question, maybe still don't but I think your asking for a way to "bulletproof your CSS" from specificity - I get the CSS bit now after seeing the other answers

Unique classnames (a bit of a oxymoron is CSS terms but heyho) added to everything are advised by most to make sure the site (not your) CSS fails as quickly as possible no matter how specific (weighted) their rules are

But you can make you widget CSS completely unique, i.e. so that it cannot be overruled by a site CSS,no matter how many ID's are in their selectors, without very much ado and without specifically classifying everything

e.g. `#mywidget div {}` could be overruled by site CSS very easily `#wrapper #content div {}` will do it - your `div` is a descendant of those two ID's too, and as their rule had 2 ID's versus your one, your CSS will lose - it's impossible to guess every permutation of a site CSS so the easiest thing is to add all those "extra" classes and why YUI and Blueprint are as they are

**however** if you write your CSS: `#mywidget>div {}` yours will likely always win, as never in their CSS will a div they're targetting likely be an **immediate child** of your widget ID (unless of course they choose to customise yours, which they could do with the 'class everything' method too)

so to bulletproof your CSS without adding classes to everything .. I assume your widget already has a unique iD wrapper? then if you don't already have an inner div wrapper, add one, it doesn't need to have a class but giving it one will place an extra layer of bulletproofing on this technique.

then prefix all your rules with `#mywidget>div.myclass` e.g. `#mywidget>div.myclass td {}` - the sites own rules, no matter how heavily weighted (many ID's and classes in a selector make a selector more weighted) theirs will fail as soon as they cannot match that particular combination - so your tr's are safe from site CSS takeover ;)

add one div or class and search and replace your CSS to add the prefix to everything.. as for how to package I've no idea

Comment: The problem is pretty much solved automatically by GWT, because it obfuscates the class names in UiBinder and CssResources. (That's one of the really great things about GWT in my opinion.)

Comment: Ah thanks, that's clever - I'll know where to look when I need to - see I said I didn't understand, I just know the logic of why it needs to be done and anything that avoids the "class everything" method is good enough for me ;)